# How can I install older PhoneGap versions using the command line?

Tags: cordova, command-line, installation, npm

How can I install an older version of *[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)*  using a command line?

I am familiar with the following installation command:

```
"$ sudo npm install -g phonegap"
```

This however only installs the latest version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`npm install -g phonegap@<version>`

You need to know the exact version number, but this should work. More info at the following link.

https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html

Comment: thanks you for your help. I tried to install phonegap 3.1.0 but without success- this is the command line I tried: "npm install -g phonegap@3.1.0"

Comment: thank you for your help. I successfully installed it. I used the following command line: npm install -g phonegap@3.1.0-0.15.0

Comment: Yeah, that is the tricky part, you have to have the exact version number

Comment: To get the exact version number: npm view cordova versions

Comment: or "npm view phonegap versions" if you want to install phonegap and not cordova (sorry, I can't edit my previous comment)

Comment: It's perfectly working. eg npm install -g corodva@3.5

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way but I use the commits section on the Phonegap Github page to snag the actual old version numbers -

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/commits/master