# There's a way to install and work with a specific Phonegap version?

Tags: cordova

There's a way to install and work with a specific Phonegap version? Currently the last is the 3.4, but I want to install in my machine the 3.3 version. Somebody knows how to do that?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311995/how-can-i-install-older-phonegap-versions-using-the-command-line/22312079#22312079

Comment: see the cordova link:-- https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface