# Cannot install my Phonegap app on iPod Touch 3G device. It says "requires a newer version of iPod software"

Tags: ios, cordova

I have just created an app using PhoneGap build and tried to test it on my iPod Touch 3G device. It says it cannot install because it requires a newer version of iPod software. My iPod has iOS version 5.1.1. That is the max OS an iPod Touch 3G device can have.

I am not sure how to move forward. I dont have any other iOS device to test my app.

Can anyone help me to work around it to get my app tested?

Or can anyone suggest me how to build an app for a lower version of iOS?
Please Note: I am using PhoneGap Build to build an *.ipa file.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what MacOS version do you have on your development Macintosh?

Comment: I have developed on a Windows 7 machine. and generated my p12 certificate through OpenSSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PhoneGap 3.5.0 or newer, it only works with iOS 6 & newer ([PhoneGap 3.5.0 dropped support for iOS 5](http://www.viewandroid.com/2014/06/phonegap-350-release-and-apache-cordova.html)).

[You'll likely need to get an older version of PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311995/how-can-i-install-older-phonegap-versions-using-the-command-line), but you are running the risk of the app not being accepted into the Apple app store (if that's what you want to do), since Apple tends to prefer only applications that have been built against the latest iOS SDK versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information... i was not aware of this. Yes i am using PhoneGap 3.5.0.